# Orcad Capture Simulation 3845

Tags: power-supply

As i ask 10 yeras ago, i trying to clear understanding how this ic work, As people mention me i don't try breadboard so i try to simulate this schematic on Orcad:
[image]

on Orcad Capture,
the result was this:
[image]

but with changing the potentiometer the pwm signal doesn't change:

[image]

Can any one help me what i do wrong ?

Comment: Isense is not used this way! It is used to sense load current not Vref,  nor is. VFB used this way as it is  for. output feedback down to REF voltage. This is just for OPEN LOOP testing

Comment: Try reading the datasheet, there has to be at least one schematic that deals with a generic use and which is meant to be the default "go to" schematic (though I remember the UCx84x to also have testing, too).